# Why original value changes if I am processing a copy of it?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, logic

I am using this routine to load some coordinates into a container, draw them, zoom into them and these sort of tasks. Then at a button click, I tend to *Reset* everything to the original or initial state. To do that I take a copy of the initial and play with the copy. But on Reset button click, I destroy the copy, take a new copy of the initial and process it. And so on.

For some reason, the original container changes when I change the copy. Could anyone spot what am I doing wrong?

In order, I load the data first and take a copy:

```
//          CoordPoint is a simple xy point 
public List<CoordPoint> MyLoadedCoords { get { return myLoadedCoords; } set { myLoadedCoords = value; }}
public List<CoordPoint> MyDisplayedCoords { get { return myDisplayedCoords; } set { myDisplayedCoords = value }}

private List<CoordPoint> myLoadedCoords;
private List<CoordPoint> myDisplayedCoords;

//..

public void LoadData()
    {
        // load points from file
        MyLoadedCoords = File.ReadLines("C:\\...\\Samples.txt") 

        // get a copy of original coords
        MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.ToList();
    }
```

Note that `MyLoadedCoords` exists **no where** in the code expect here (And in the Reset function, down). Then I process the copy `MyDisplayedCoords` several places similar to this:

```
public void UpdateDisplayPosition()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < MyDisplayedCoords.Count; i++)
    {  
        MyDisplayedCoords[i].X += XCoordOffset; //some processed values
        MyDisplayedCoords[i].Y += YCoordOffset; //some processed values
    }
}
```

Reset Button I do this:

```
public void ResetZoom()
{
    MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.ToList(); // I set break point here
    AdjustInitialDisplayPosition();
    DrawImage();
}
```

`ResetZoom()` does not do what is expected, When I debug and break on  `MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords;` I see that `MyLoadedCoords` contains the exact same values/objects as `MyDisplayedCoords`

**EDIT:**

I implemented `IClonable` and "overrided" the `Clone()` function in my class but it did **NOT** work:

```
public class CoordPoint : ICloneable
{
    // .. 

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new CoordPoint {X = X, Y = Y, Z = Z, Color = Color};
    }
}
```

However, with**out** the `IClonable`, **this "copying" works** as cloning as [**H.B**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) answered:

```
MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.Select(c => new CoordPoint { X = c.X, Y = c.Y, Z = c.Z, Color = c.Color }).ToList();
```

Comment: You aren't getting a copy, you are actually working on a new list with all of the same data pointers.  To solve this you will need to either use Clone, which doesn't support nested reference types or implement your own deep clone.

Comment: @FirstStep, CoordPoint, is it class or struct? Because if it's a class, .ToList() will create new list which will contain the same references.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan it is a class. Interesting I did not know that, so if it was a struct it could have worked?

Comment: @FirstStep, Here is an [mini-example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/quX8BM). You can see that Lists has different hashcodes, but their content are the same.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan I see. Thanks I learned something new today

Comment: @FirstStep , you're welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords` does not copy anything, it assigns a reference to the same object to a property, now both properties point to the same object.

To copy a list you could use on of the Linq methods (which always return a new list):

```
MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.ToList();
```

To deep copy you could do something like this, then the instances in the lists will also be different:

```
MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.Select(c =>
                                       new CoordPoint { X = c.X, Y = c.Y }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am doing this `MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.ToList()` initially, so it should assign a copy no?

Comment: Yes, but your `ResetZoom` does not do that and from that point on you would have the same object, maybe you call that somewhere?

Comment: Then you need to deep copy as suggested by Vishnu.

Comment: @FirstStep: Added a method for deep copying (if X and Y are the only properties and you have a empty constructor, otherwise adjust it accordingly).

Comment: Hi, I have couple additional properties `Color` and `Z` which is just zero for now. I have two constructors: One with parameters to _All_ private properties, and one without any parameters but it sets _All_ properties to some default values inside. Do I need to change anything before applying your solution?

Comment: @FirstStep: You should copy all properties and fields accordingly, if this cannot be achieved with the public interface/constructors, your class needs to implement a clone method that takes care of that. Just make sure that the copy result is **logically identical** to your source, the method by which you achieve this is irrelevant.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. This works: `MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.Select(c => new CoordPoint { X = c.X, Y = c.Y, Z = c.Z, Color = c.Color }).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

To add on H.B's answer,

`ToList` creates a new `List` object, but the objects inside the lists are just references to the same `object` unless they're immutable objects(string for example or primitive types).

Your original `List` object will not be affected in this case (addition of new objects/removals etc.) but changes to objects will reflect in both. Because they refer same object.

You can either follow H.B's answer to copy new as new objects or follow the below process which is more clean and proper.

Implement `ICloneable` interface in `CoordPoint` class. override the `Clone` method and call it during copying. A bit long method, but this way your code `Linq` will look proper.

```
public class CoordPoint : ICloneable
{
  //rest of your code here

  public object Clone()
  {
    return new CoordPoint
                 {
                   X= X,
                   Y = Y
                 };
  }
}
```

Then your `Linq` code will be,

```
MyDisplayedCoords = MyLoadedCoords.Select(c =>  (CoordPoint)c.Clone()).ToList();
```

Comment: "unless they're immutable objects" should probably be "unless they're value types".

Comment: Hi, so how could I fix that?

Comment: @FirstStep please check if my solution works for you

Answer (score 0):

When you 'copy' your list object you are getting a new list, but the items in that list are all still pointing to the same items as the first.

The easiest way to to get around this problem is the `ICloneable` interface, here is a short sample:

```
public class MyObject : ICloneable
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>() { new MyObject { Property = "FirstObject" } };
var clonedList = list.Select(x => x.Clone());
```